# iOS Swift Rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to add a rectangular shape (curve as shown in picture) to my existing UIView.

[image: New Design].

This is the code I have implemented:

```
func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let y:CGFloat = 20
    let curveTo:CGFloat = 0

    let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
    myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
    myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: curveTo))
    myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
    myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
    myBezier.close()
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setLineWidth(4.0)
    UIColor.yellow.setFill()
    myBezier.fill()
}
```

Just to try and get a rectangle path to appear, however, when I open it in the simulator there is nothing. I believe it is because my other elements are overlayed on top of it is this correct? My full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/511K4WyQ)

Thanks for your help.

[image: My View]

[image]

Comment: you may need to call `setNeedsDisplay() ` after your view is added to your viewController's view

Comment: why have you decided to put curveTo to 0? Also what value has your rect.height? The view hierarchy your using would help too

Comment: Looking at your full code... 1) your drawRect() func is *inside* your viewDidLoad() func - definitely not where you want it. 2) drawRect() is a method of UIView - you are trying to put it in UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code. The UIViewController don't have overridden message drawRect. You should create custom class derived from UIView and override message drawRect there.

Answer (score 0):

This could be made much more flexible, but it might suit your needs. If it doesn't, it could be a good starting point for you to get to what you want.

If you haven't looked at custom components / subclassing UIView / using IBInspectable and IBDesignable, this probably won't make much sense, so you might have some reading to do :)

```
//
//  RoundedBottomImageView.swift
//  SW3IBDesign
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 2/27/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 DonMag. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class RoundedBottomImageView: UIView {

    var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
        didSet { self.imageView.image = image }
    }

    @IBInspectable var roundingValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        doMyInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        doMyInit()
    }

    func doMyInit() {

        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
        addSubview(imageView)

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        imageView.frame = self.bounds

        let rect = self.bounds
        let y:CGFloat = rect.size.height - roundingValue
        let curveTo:CGFloat = rect.size.height

        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
        myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: curveTo))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        myBezier.close()

        let maskForPath = CAShapeLayer()
        maskForPath.path = myBezier.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskForPath

    }

}
```

Example app: https://github.com/DonMag/IBDesignInspect

Edit: Example now includes buttons to demonstrate changing the image via code.

Edit2: Example app now has an Alternate Storyboard to show how the image can be "path clipped" without using a custom subclass.

Comment: Hi there, I checked your Github project but I am unsure how you picked what image to round. I have implemented the same file you provided but I am unsure how to select what image view this effects.

Comment: If you look at the properties in Interface Builder, you should see an Image property and a "roundingValue" property. You can add an image to it just like you would a normal UIImageView - either in IB or by setting the .image property in code.

Comment: Within attributes inspector or size inspector?

Comment: I made a few changes to the example project, so it might be a little clearer (it now has 3 images to choose from - or you can add your own). You can set the image either in the Attributes Inspector or via Code.

Comment: I have added images showing my project vs yours it seems you have more options for custom classes on ImageViews than me?

Comment: Hmmm... OK, to more directly answer your initial question, I changed the example app around to show how it would be done *without* creating a custom subclass. The advantage to the subclass is a) it can be easily reused and b) using IBDesignable you can *see* it in Interface Builder. Take a look at the updated project, see if it makes any more sense.